# How to get the text(data) separately in the list of arrays in kml file? android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I want to get the list of restaurants in my current location. I want to get the text (information) alone from the xml file. I am getting it, but other unwanted tag's text in the xml file are also coming, that is (OK, html attributions...); Give me some ideas to get the text(Information) ALONE.

```
    // MyLocationActivity.class
package com.sesh.mylocation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyLocationActivity extends Activity {

    final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        fetchGooglePlaces();
        parsingFile();
    }

    public void parsingFile() {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/temp2.xml"));
            new XmlPullParsing(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void fetchGooglePlaces() {
        try {
            URL google = new URL(
                    " https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&types=food&key=AIzaSyDMtpRbFp03lBx5bqoGdPuD2TzqbtZdzbM");

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    "/mnt/sdcard/temp2.xml"));

            BufferedWriter bout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    fout));

            URLConnection tc = google.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                bout.write(line);
            }

            bout.flush();
            bout.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }
}

//XmlPullParsing.java

package com.sesh.mylocation;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.util.Log;

public class XmlPullParsing {

    protected XmlPullParser xmlpullparser;
    String output;
    String TAG = "XmlPullParsing";

    public XmlPullParsing(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

            xmlpullparser = factory.newPullParser();

            xmlpullparser.setInput(is, "UTF-8");

            int eventType = 0;

            eventType = xmlpullparser.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                parseTag(eventType);
                eventType = xmlpullparser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }

    void parseTag(int event) {
        String tagName;
        switch (event) {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG: 
            tagName = xmlpullparser.getName().toLowerCase();

            if (tagName.equals("result")) {
                Log.e("Tag name is:", tagName);

                if (tagName.equals("name")) {
                    Log.e("Name:", tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("vicinity")) {
                    Log.e("Vicinity:", tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("type")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Type:" + tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("type")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Type:" + tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("type")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Type:" + tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("geometry")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Geometry:" + tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("location")) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Location:" + tagName);
                    if (tagName.equals("lat")) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Lat:" + tagName);
                        if (tagName.equals("lng")) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Long:" + tagName);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (tagName.equals("rating")){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Rating:" + tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("icon")){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Icon:" + tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("reference")){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Reference:" + tagName);
                }

                if (tagName.equals("id")){
                    Log.e(TAG, "ID:" + tagName);
                }
                }
            break;

        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

            Log.e("Text", xmlpullparser.getText());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```